# Cant click on an img with Sikili

Tags: selenium, sikuli

I want to click on an ing with Sikuli. I use this:

```
Screen screen - new screen()
screen.click(getData("ImagePath") + imageName);
```

** getData - I take the path from XML.

The test is passed but the img is not clicked.

I received this msg:

[log] CLICK on L(1269,364)@S(0)[0,0 1366x768] (526 msec)

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be either a sync issue or wrong region

- Use **img.highlight** method to first check if you're actually working on the expected region
- Use conditions such as **if exists(img, timeout)** or **wait(img, timeout)** to make sure your image is appearing on the screen at the right time.